# Stateful widget does not rebuild

Tags: flutter

Page A is a stateful widget

Page B is a stateful widget and child of Page A.

When I called `setState()`, Page A's widget is rebuilt, but Page B did not

Why is it?

Comment: If you can share the code, It will be more easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It is a expected behavior page b will not redraw or rebuilt until and unless you called **setState()** from page B.

some how you have to call setState() from page B.